# Compare deeply nested object and save the differences in the default object along with other properties (which didn't change)

Tags: javascript, object

As the title suggests I have a deeply nested object.

My scenario is my source dataset is the default object/config of my child component. Now when one needs to use anywhere in the project they can change the config according to their needs.

What I am currently doing is spreading the whole object first then changing the necessary object which I am aware is a bad practice. I need to make the config/object more flexible.

From the parent component one will only send the values they want to change and inside the child component I will only update those values which were changed and will keep other properties as it is.

My source dataset:

```
sourceDataset = {
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  showHint: {
   enable: true,
   format: 'test',
  },
  primary: {
    title: 'Primary Title',
    style: {
       color: 'red',
       size: 24
    }
  },
  secondary: {
     title: 'Second Title',
     min: 0,
     max: 0,
     style: {
        color: 'blue',
        size: 54
     }
  }
}
```

Example type of object which I might receive from parent component

```
secondary = {
  height: 50,
  showHint: {
    enable: false
  },
  primary: {
    title: 'Primary Title 2',
    style: {
      size: 45
    }
  },
  secondary: {
    style: {
      color: 'green'
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Output

```
result = {
  height: 50, // changed
  width: 100,
  showHint: {
   enable: false, // changed
   format: 'test',
  },
  primary: {
    title: 'Primary Title 2', // changed
    style: {
       color: 'red',
       size: 45 // Changed
    }
  },
  secondary: {
     title: 'Second Title',
     min: 0,
     max: 0,
     style: {
        color: 'green', // changed
        size: 54
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to add your js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one way of doing this, is like below, using a **recursive function** :

```js
let sourceDataset = {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    showHint: {
       enable: true,
       format: 'test',
    },
    primary: {
        title: 'Primary Title',
        style: {
            color: 'red',
            size: 24
        }
    },
    secondary: {
        title: 'Second Title',
        min: 0,
        max: 0,
        style: {
            color: 'blue',
            size: 54
        }
    }
};

let secondary = {
    height: 50,
    showHint: {
        enable: false
    },
    primary: {
        title: 'Primary Title 2',
        style: {
            size: 45
        }
    },
    secondary: {
        style: {
            color: 'green'
        },
        info: {
            text:"lorem ipsum"
        }
    }
}
    
function callRecursiveAgain(sourceKey,changedDataKey){
    if(sourceKey && 
    changedDataKey &&
    typeof sourceKey == "object" &&
    typeof changedDataKey == "object" && 
    !Array.isArray(sourceKey) &&
    !Array.isArray(changedDataKey) && 
     Object.keys(changedDataKey).length>0 &&
     Object.keys(sourceKey).length>0
    ){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
        
function replaceChangesRecursively(source,changedData){
    Object.keys(changedData)?.map(key=>{
        if(callRecursiveAgain(source[key],changedData[key])){
            replaceChangesRecursively(source[key],changedData[key]);
        }
        else{
            source[key] = changedData[key];
            console.log(`${key} ---> changed`);
        }
    })
}
replaceChangesRecursively(sourceDataset,secondary);
console.log(sourceDataset);   //newSouceDataset
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for response. I do have one query though. There could be situations where its possible that a new key can be added in `secondary` dataset which also needs to be merged in the new dataset.. In the current solution that you provided, if a new key is given with a value, that key/value is ignored

Comment: I've modified the code. So `secondary` object can update `sourceDataset` no matter whether it has a new property or not. I added a new `info` object in `secondary` for testing. It worked fine.

Comment: Hello @mahooresorkh, Thank you for you updated code. This solution worked as expected.. Thank you again. I will accept your code as accepted answer. I had one more query, would it be possible to do the whole solution using lodash? Lodash methods such _.merge(), _.close(), would it be possible?

Comment: There is a bunch of very useful `lodash` methods, which I personally have not studied them all. But there is a good chance that this task can be done by one or some of them.